# An error occurred during local report processing - SSDT

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, rdlc, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2005-express

I am planning to shift from Crystal Reports to SSDT.
I have created a Report Project in Visual Studio and am trying to create a basic report pulling 3 columns from a single table.

My query is:

```
select SRNO, EMPSRNO, PYMONTH 
  from PYHeader
 where PYMONTH = 'Jan-2018'
```

I have created a Datasource and Dataset, dragged a table control in Design view and dragged the 3 columns to the 3 columns of the table.

The code runs properly in the Query Designer but when I try to Preview it, it shows the error:

> "An error occurred during local report processing. An error has
>   occurred during report processing."

Could someone please tell me what is wrong?

Note: I have deactivated the antivirus and windows firewall too.

---

Components:
I am using:
Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1,
SQL Server 2005 Express,
.NET Framework 4.6.01038, SSDT_14.0.61712.050_EN, Win 10 Pro 64-Bit

---

Additional error logs:

===================================

Could not connect to the report server http://localhost/reportserver. Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer)

===================================

Unable to connect to the remote server (Microsoft.ReportingServices.RsClient)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListItemTypes()
   at ReportServiceClient2010.CheckAuthenticated()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ICredentials credentials, String& authCookieName, Cookie& authCookie, EndpointType& endpointType)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.DetectEndpointAndAuthenticate(String url, ConnectionProperties& connectionProperties)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportClientManager.GetCredentials(String url, CancelFlag cancelFlag, IPromptCreds promptCredentials)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Project.ReportProjectDeployer.PrepareDeploy()

===================================

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80 (System)

---

Program Location:

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved.
I didn't have SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS) installed - in Services.msc it should have shown "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)" which wasn't there.
Besides, my current version of SQL Server (i.e. 2005) wasn't compatible.

I had to uninstall SQL Server 2005 Express. While installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, it had an option to install "Reporting Service".

That, and a few configuration later, its working fine now.